# ASP.NET MVC partial view and form action name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I create a partial view that has a form with assigned id?
I got as far as:

```
using (Html.BeginForm(?action?,"Candidate",FormMethod.Post,new {id="blah"}))
```

Partial view is used for both Create and Edit so first parameter `?action?` will be different. I can't figure out what value of `?action?` supposed to be.

---

**UPDATE:**

I guess I was not clear enough with the question. What I ended up doing is splitting `Request.RawUrl` to get controller name and action name:

```
 string[] actionUrlParts = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl.Split('/');
 using (Html.BeginForm(actionUrlParts.Length >= 2? actionUrlParts[2] : "",
        actionUrlParts.Length >= 1 ? actionUrlParts[1] : "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "blah" }))
```

Kind of ugly but it works. Is there a better way to get an action name inside the partial view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass in the action to be performed via ViewData.

In your action that renders the view, create a ViewData item for the postback action. In your form reference this ViewData item to fill in the action parameter.  Alternatively, you can create a view-only model that includes the action and the actual model as properties and reference it from there.

Example using ViewData:

```
using (Html.BeginForm( (string)ViewData["PostBackAction"], "Candidate", ...
```

Rendering actions:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     ViewData["PostBackAction"] = "New";
     ...
}


public ActionResult Edit( int id )
{
     ViewData["PostBackAction'] = "Update";
     ...
}
```

Example using Model

```
public class UpdateModel
{
     public string Action {get; set;}
     public Candidate CandidateModel { get; set; }
}

using (Html.BeginForm( Model.Action, "Candidate", ...
```

Rendering actions:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     var model = new UpdateModel { Action = "New" };

     ...

     return View(model);
}


public ActionResult Edit( int id )
{
     var model = new UpdateModel { Action = "Update" };

     model.CandidateModel = ...find corresponding model from id...

     return View(model);
}
```

**EDIT**: Based on your comment, if you feel that this should be done in the view (though I disagree), you could try some logic based off the ViewContext.RouteData

```
<%
    var action = "Create";
    if (this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] == "Edit")
    {
        action = "Update";
    }
    using (Html.BeginForm( action, "Candidate", ... 
    {
 %>
```

Comment: This will work but I don't really want to change Controller code to handle something that View should be able to figure out

Comment: I added alternative this is entirely view-based, though I would think that the proper place to control what action to postback to would be in the controller.

Comment: Yep. That's exactly what I was looking for. The action name is in
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]

Comment: @Dmitriy -- updated to use values property in example.  I still think that the controller ought to control the flow in the app either by choosing a view with a fixed postback url or supplying the postback url to a view with a dynamic one.  Views should responsible for rendering, not control logic.

Comment: Thank you for the info as it solved an issue I had with extending some conditional functionality to a Partial.  Re the code example of using the ViewContext.RouteData I needed to cast it as a string for the comparision as below but was great for getting me in the right direciton.  <%if ((string)this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] == "Create") {%> - Thanks, Norman

Answer (score 1):

Pass nulls as action and controller. Extension will use just current action and current controller

```
using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id="Model" }))
```

Action generated for form will be the same as parent view of this partial view.

It generates

```
<form action="/Orders/Edit/1" id="Model" method="post">
```

for url http://localhost:1214/Orders/Edit/1

... and this

```
<form action="/Orders/Create" id="Model" method="post">
```

for url http://localhost:1214/Orders/Create

Answer (score 0):

```
<% html.RenderPartial("MyUserControl", Model.ID) %>
```

Comment: Hello, please do not post code only answers, your answer could be greatly improved with some explanation of what your code is doing and how this solves OP's problem.

Comment: Code only answers are low quality and subject to deletion, there should always be at least one or two sentences (optimally a paragraph) about what question you are addressing assumptions, conditions, pitfalls, etc).